# Upload adobe air app in google play store

Tags: flash, air, google-play

This is probably a very naive question. I am a Flash developer and have recently started working in Adobe Air. Initially I used to publish the .apk files locally. However, a new project demands one of the files I developed to be uploaded in Google Play Store. As I am completely new to Android platform, I require some guidance in this regard. I have searched Google but the results are not quite to my understanding. Can anyone kindly provide me with some guideline as to the steps I may take to upload my app to Google Play Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here.

https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/

Once you have signed up and have access to the developer portal you should see the +Add new application button and forms to fill in.